# How to use git for a group project (with eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, git

I am trying to figure out how to use Git in a group (php programming) project. We need to be able to commit to the same project individually. I have read different things about git and realized that there are quite a lot of ways for achieving this. 
My question is: What should I download and how do I set it up the best way? And how can this be used through eclipse? 
Also, should the "GIT" folder/project be located online? If so, where should this be uploaded to?

(I have read that the git plugin for eclipse isn't the best solution at all)

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to read the [EGit User Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide).

No need to read the whole thing, just come back to it whenever you're stuck in using it.

Comment: Okay i will give it a go :) And it is possible to commit to an online folder from various places right? update/make changes to the same project i mean.

Comment: @user68612 Of course. You can use `EGit` in parallel with an OS client, like GitBash or GitHub.